# Any way to omit blank cells in a CSV file from plots?

Tags: r, csv, ggplot2

New to R trying to make a simple plot based on two columns of csv data.

Here is the head of the csv

```
    ID        Value
1 HHK2 -15.87166864
2 HHK2             
3 HHK2             
4 HHK2 -21.56075777
5 HHK2 -16.11445311
6 HHK2  -34.8690159
```

Here is the plot command, but the plot is incorrect.

```
library(ggplot2)

raw <- read.csv("mycsv")

ggplot(raw,aes(x=ID,y=Value,color=ID)) + geom_point()
```

Anyway to tell the plot to ignore the dataframe cells that have no value?  If I delete those lines from the .csv then it plots fine.

Comment: In what way does it not plot correctly? Can you provide the output from `dput(head(raw))`?

Comment: This site won't let me post pictures of the graphs which is ridculous.  Oh well I can do the same thing in JMP in no time and not deal with the headache.

Comment: @user3646105 If you are no longer interested in an answer to the question, you may delete it, otherwise if you would still like help, please provide the data requested.

Comment: @user3646105 You can still insert a link to your image.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to plot the rows with blanks, you could use:

```
ggplot(raw[!is.na(raw$Value),],aes(x=ID,y=Value,color=ID)) + geom_point()
```

which creates a subset of raw omitting the rows containing `NA` values caused by reading in blanks, and then uses your plotting command on this.